# How do you execute custom SQL in EF CTP4

Tags: entity-framework-4

Using Entity Framework CPT4 is there a way to execute a custom command or script?

for example:

```
_dbSet.Provider.Execute("Truncate Table Users");
```

FWIW; I will be using this in the class setup for my unit tests and will setup the tables with clean data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx) method.

> Executes an arbitrary command directly against the data source using the existing connection.
>
> Calling the ExecuteStoreCommand method is equivalent to calling the ExecuteNonQuery method of the DbCommand class.

Some other good information:  [Tip 41 – How to execute T-SQL directly against the database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/11/07/tip-41-how-to-execute-t-sql-directly-against-the-database.aspx)

With this example for `ExecuteStoreCommand`:

```
// 10% inflation day! 
ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE Products SET Price = Price * 1.1");
```

Comment: The key here is that in CTP4 the DBContext is introduced. However; many of the commands you need are down in the ObjectContext.

Comment: As of 2011/12/16, ctx.Database.ExecuteStoreCommand(...) appears to be the correct command.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [ndbunit](http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/) to setup and teardown your database for unit tests

---

**Edit:**

This is what we are using on our application for unit/integration testing our data access layer which is actually implemented using EF4. It's fairly straightforward and provides a nice way to inject and cleanup repeatable test data.

However, we also have the need to delete/truncate a table in the application logic itself using EF. So to answer your original question,  we've just incorporate the "delete from table" script in a stored proc which we then call from EF using

```
_dataContext.ExecuteFunction("SchemaName.MyTableDeleteProc");
```

Comment: _dbContext.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("Something");

Answer (score 0):

The quickest workaround I can think of is the use of stored procs. An alternative is to use batch delete described http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx <-- here, but the code is based on Linq2Sql, not EF, you will have to port it.